# MySQL Join with the wrong results

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a quick question regarding a JOIN.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT
products.name AS name,
products.last_scanned AS last_scanned,
products.last_scanned AS last_changed,

ph.price AS price,
ph.mirror_price AS mirror_price,
ph.change_date AS change_date,

ph.dioPlusZapPrice AS dioPlusZapPrice,
ph.dioPlusSitePrice AS dioPlusSitePrice,

ph.inkDepotZapPrice AS inkDepotZapPrice,
ph.inkDepotSitePrice AS inkDepotSitePrice,

ph.misradiaZapPrice AS misradiaZapPrice,
ph.misradiaSitePrice AS misradiaSitePrice,

ph.netPrintZapPrice AS netPrintZapPrice,
ph.netPrintSitePrice AS netPrintSitePrice,

img1.image_blob AS dioPlusImage,
img2.image_blob AS inkDepotImage,
img3.image_blob AS misradiaImage,
img4.image_blob AS netPrintImage

FROM
price_history ph

LEFT JOIN products ON products.productID=ph.productID

LEFT JOIN imagedata img1 ON img1.id = ph.imagename_dioPlus
LEFT JOIN imagedata img2 ON img2.id = ph.imagename_inkDepot
LEFT JOIN imagedata img3 ON img3.id = ph.imagename_misradia
LEFT JOIN imagedata img4 ON img4.id = ph.imagename_netPrint

ORDER BY ph.change_date DESC
```

The result of this query is:

```
Brother MFC-L2700DW|2015-06-26 15:47|2015-06-26 15:47|949|949|2015-06-26 15:47|949|949|969|999|0|0|0|0|[BLOB - 217.9 KiB]|[BLOB - 217.9 KiB]|NULL|NULL
```

which displays the same blob.

This is my imagadata table:

```
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------+
| ID | image_blob         | ID | imagename                            |
+----+-----------+-----+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | [BLOB - 19.5 KiB]  |  1 | a5052c6e-1120-4ece-994d-2cdac7e7baa4 |
|  2 | [BLOB - 217.9 KiB] |  2 | 1ed6f935-a44a-4f07-9c6b-fa51da5d4bdb |
|  3 | [BLOB - 217.9 KiB] |  3 | 8acced70-17ae-4a65-8466-6b910c674869 |
+----+-----------+----+-----------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see from the image, This is wrong since the ID is different in `imagedata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 rows with identical values:

```
2 - [BLOB - 217.9 KiB]; 
3 - [BLOB - 217.9 KiB];
```

So if row in `price_history` table containt such data:

```
imagename_dioPlus imagename_inkDepot
2                 3
```

it will output

```
[BLOB - 217.9 KiB] [BLOB - 217.9 KiB]
```

no matter that they have different `ids`. Trouble is they have same descriptions.